# Showing comments from two blog post entries on a single page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress page *School* I have two different blog. let's say blog *A* and blog *B*. When use on either blog *A* or blog *B* he can make comment. Now I want to make the comments mutual of both blogs.
i.e 
If someone comments on the blog *A* it should display like below:

1. on the blog *A* itself
2. on the *School* page
3. and also on the blog *B*

[image: Comment demo]
So no matter where user has  comment on the above mentioned three pages comment go on all three pages.

Comment: Check out: http://generatewp.com/wp/wp_comment_query

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [rss feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) to get comments and load those into the page.
If it is a multisite you could take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7014/list-recent-comments-from-across-a-multi-site-network).
If the sites are separate but on the same server you could make a connection to there databases and query the comments you need.

You will need to code something yourself at the very least.

Comment: sorry for confusion.. but here blog means blogpost on the same website. so i have to display comments of two blogpost in a single page on same website

Comment: hey janw .. can you help me on this? Can we discuss it on chat room ?

Comment: Yes sure, this is far easier. Give me an hour, got other stuff to do first.

Comment: @Abhigyan I added a new answer which should help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get comments of a post by using [WP_Comment_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query). A rough example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_ID' => 1 //Add the postID of the post you need here
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
  foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    // here you can display the comment in the way you want
    echo 'Author: ' . $comment->comment_author . '<br/>';
    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
  }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
?>
```

Do take a look at the article mentioned above. I don't know how you want to get the `post_ID` but that's up to you. Let me know if you need help.